# Splitting a date using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a date using the following piece of JavaScript

```
    var dSplit = getDate.split("/");
    var newDate = dSplit[2] + "-" + dSplit[0] + "-" + dSplit[1];
```

I get the following output

```
    2014 12:00:00 AM-11-25
```

The output i require is

```
    2014-11-25 12:00:00 AM
```

Please Help.

Comment: What is getDate? what value did you assign to it previously?

Comment: Is it `new Date();` your are calling `getDate`?

Comment: Instead of splitting, try using "replace" (assuming that your variable is string).  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp  Just seen you'r var is date.

Comment: What is the original format?

Comment: w3schools.com/  is bad use developer.mozilla.org

Comment: Tambo, it was the first answer in for "javascript replace".  (I'm too lazy to make bigger search).

Comment: what is the output of dSplit?

Comment: So your input is `11/25/2014 12:00:00`, so `split` is doing exactly what you asked it to--splitting that string on slashes into `['11', '14', '2014 12:00:00']`. Perhaps you should split on the space first, then split the first result again on slashes.

Comment: @torazaburo : Ok dude, I am gonna try that.

Comment: But what you should really do is use a date parsing and formatting library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var getDate = '11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM';
var newDate = getDate.replace(/^\S+/, function(date) { 
  var d = date.split('/'); 
  return d[2] + '-' + d[0] + '-' + d[1]; 
});
// 2014-11-25 12:00:00 AM
```

This approach allows to process both datetime strings (similar to '11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM', like in your answer) and date strings (like '11/25/2014'). The key here is processing only first sequence of non-whitespace characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You may format the date to string as you want, using the next function:

```
        function formatDate(date) {
            var ans = date.getFullYear();
            ans += "-" + (date.getMonth()+1);
            ans += "-" + date.getDay();
            ans += "  " + date.getHours();
            ans += ":" + date.getMinutes();
            document.write (ans);
        }
```

This way, even if the user's browser converts date to string on different order (longer format etc.) you have full control on the output string.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpfull,pass$val alone in function

```
var dateString=$val.split(" ");
var dateformat=dateString[0].split("-");
var dateVal= dateformat[0] + "/" + dateformat[1] + "/" + dateformat[2];

$.date = function(dateObject) {

 var d = new Date(dateObject);
 var day = d.getDate();
 var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = d.getFullYear();
 if (day < 10) {
    day = "0" + day;
 }
 if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
 }
 var date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

 return date;
};
```